# Javascript returning [object Object], which needs to be removed

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I need some help with my JavaScript, i am trying to sorting XML data with the help of JavaScript, and i am successful doing the sorting part, but the output is returning some garbage object `[object Object]`, which i don't want it to be printed out, so i need some help to get this thing fixed so that i get a proper output. I am attaching a live fiddle. All these needs to be done with JavaScript and not JQUERY.

I don't want `[object Object],[object Object]` to be printed as output

[Live Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aliparvez20/nsZS8/6/)

---

```
bookstore 
   |
   |__book 
   |    |_____title
   |    |_____author
   |    |_____year
   |    |_____price
   |
   |__book 
   |
   |__book 
   |
   |__book
```

---

Thank You

Comment: That's generally what happens when you try to output an object, the string representation is outputted, which is [object, Object].

Comment: Why is this tagged with jQuery???

Comment: Okay, then what code should i use to stop [object, Object] to be printed?

Comment: You're definitley not going to get a code here. You have a flaw in the design. Maybe I could point you to it: look at your recursion. At what point does `obj.name` get printed onto the screen? Remember, `{name:"name", children:...}` is also an object. And so, would produce  `[object Object]`. (When should the recursion stop?)

Comment: **please use this code instead** http://jsbin.com/vogehuru/2/edit

Comment: I dont use JQUERY.i am codeing program with javascript

Answer (score 1):

This is coming from where you have

```
for (var prop in obj){
    li = document.createElement("li");
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(obj[prop]));
    // ...
}
```

You're not taking into account when `typeof obj[prop]; // "object"` until after appending it to the tree, and `createTextNode` will invoke *ToString* on it's parameters, giving you `"[object Object]"`

Comment: @user3350333 http://jsfiddle.net/65tYj/ , open your _Console_ and look between where I comment `// xxxxxxxxxx` in the code, too

Comment: Sir i didn't get what are you trying to do, but still the probram is not working